# DynamoDB : Slow Read when queried for first time

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Following is my code :

```
error_log('before query'.date("H:i:s:ms"));
$response = $client->query(array(
                                 "TableName" => "user",
                                 "KeyConditions" => array(
                                 "userId" => array( "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
                                 "AttributeValueList" => array(
                                                               array(Type::NUMBER => 2)
                                                               ))),
                                ));
error_log('after query'.date("H:i:s:ms"));
print_r($response);
```

My tables Read capacity is 6 reads/sec

**Output of Error logs**

before query 16:05:29:0229

after query 16:05:32:0232

**Question:** Why it took 3 secs to read the user for first time? If I add one more query after my first query then it take less than 1 sec to respond.

Any light on the path would be helpful

-Thanks

Comment: This is most probably something to do with your PHP installation rather than Dynamo. Are you using a Framework like Symfony of Zend? Are you using xdebug? Are you using a cache like APC or php 5.5 opcache? Any of those could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you are executing this query from different region than database's instance or from local.

If you haven't uploaded file with this query to the same region as your dynamoDb then it will take some time to build connection with your DB instance. Try to upload this script on the same region's server as your DB and then try again.