# DynamoDB querying in 2017

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

There are few similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131191/how-do-you-query-dynamodb) out there, but looks like they are outdated.

Does DynamoDB still have problems with querying or not?

Use case: table contains users with parameters: name, phone, email, groupId, created, etc...
I want to get all users with `groupId = 1`, `name iLike 'jo'` and `created > a_year_ago_timestamp`.

Looks like this is possible already, according to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html).

Or this is another highly expensive scanning operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using the **Query API** of DynamoDB, it is not an expensive scanning operation. Using Query API implies that you know the **hash key** of the table.

In the above case, I assume `groupId` is a hash key of the table. Please note that you can't use `CONTAINS` or `GE` (i.e. greater than) for hash key attribute on `KeyConditionExpression`.

So, `groupId` must be hash key in order to use Query API. Otherwise, you may need to look at GSI (Global Secondary Index) in order to use Query API.

Obviously, if you use **Scan API** with `FilterExpression`, it would be a costly operation.

Comment: Something is wrong. How is it possible that this database was lacking such a huge and important feature as querying for a long time and now it suddenly has it. I'm afraid it can be some trick, something like material-view creation at the first invocation of a query. But if query will be different each time, it's performance may slow down.  What is "hash key"? Is it like table identificator?

Comment: also, docs says "Developer Guide (API Version 2012-08-10)". There were no such feature a year or so ago. Why it says 2012?

Comment: Hash key is like primary key on relational database. The data is partitioned based on hash key for better scalability (i.e. Scaling horizondally). This is the main feature of NoSQL database.

Comment: 2012-08-10 was the major version. After that, only patches applied on DynamoDB (i.e. no major changes introduced on database design level). This doesn't mean that API hasn't been updated.

Comment: if it's a "users" table, then hash key will be "user_id" or something. And it will be unique per each user. Right? So, if i have table with 10 thousands users and i need to find first 50 of them based on, say, 15 different conditions at once (booleans, `iLike` strings, numbers, dates), DynamoDB will do what i need without any kind of "but"?

Comment: As I said earlier, you can achieve this. However, it will not be efficient in terms of performance and cost. DynamoDB gives you better result if you know the hash key. Otherwise, everything is full table scan which consumes read capacity units (which is directly related to cost). Alternate option is to create index accordingly for your use case. Hash key of index (i.e. GSI) need not be unique.